# Inserting a query variable as an attribute in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

What I am trying to achieve here is to insert the query "$interviewdoc/interviews/interview/@pID" as an attribute called posting, inside the tag "best", which wraps the query "$skillWhighestscore"

Is there some sort of syntax in xQuery that allows for such a thing?

```
let $prev := <best posting={$interviewdoc/interviews/interview/@pID}
 resume="temp">{$skillWhighestscore}</best> return $prev
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert the query, or to insert the result of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to wrap the dynamically evaluated attribute value with quotes to make the result well-formed :

```
<best posting="{$interviewdoc/interviews/interview/@pID}"
 resume="temp">{$skillWhighestscore}</best>
```

Quick test : http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/2f25c1ab6f69312df433ccb317f09248